# Changing html of span doesn't load the all the properties

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, post

I am trying to make a comments-reply system on my website. I have made all php files, but am stuck changing the vote counts here.

[image]

As shown in the image, on voting once, the content is changed perfectly, i can change the class from `upvote` to `upvoted` or `downvote` to `downvoted` or as I need to.

But the problem is, once the class is changed, the content too is changed. But I cannot vote again, till the page is reloaded.

Before this code, i was changing class using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

That too resulted in same problem.

.html

```
<span class='votes'><span data-id='8' class='comment vote upvote'></span>".$row['downvotes']."</span>
```

myId is data-id.
as you can see, i am changing html content of variable x using data.

But once changed, i cannot vote again.

.js(jquery)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#notice').hide();
    $("span").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('vote')){
        var myId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var action = 'a';
        if($(this).hasClass('upvote')){
            action = 'upvote';
        } else if($(this).hasClass('upvoted')){
            action = 'upvoted';
        } else if($(this).hasClass('downvote')){
            action = 'downvote';
        } else if($(this).hasClass('downvoted')){
            action = 'downvoted';
        }
        var url;
        var class1;
        var class2;
        if(action=='upvote'){
            class1 = "upvoted";
            class2 = "downvote";
        }else if(action=='upvoted'){
            class1 = "upvote";
            class2 = "downvote";
        }else if(action=='downvote'){
            class1 = "upvote";
            class2 = "downvoted";
        }else if(action=='downvoted'){
            class1 = "upvote";
            class2 = "downvote";
        }
        var content;
        /* If voted element is video */
            if($(this).hasClass('video')){
                    url = base_url + 'forms/votes/vote_video.php';
                    content = 'video';
            }
        /* If voted element is comment */
            else if($(this).hasClass('comment')){
                    url = base_url + 'forms/votes/vote_comment.php';
                    content = 'comment';
            }
        var x  = $(this).parent();
        if(action=='upvote'){
            content1 = "<span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote upvoted'></span>";
            content2 = " <span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote downvote'></span>";
        }else if(action=='upvoted'){
            content1 = "<span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote upvote'></span>";
            content2 = " <span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote downvote'></span>";
        }else if(action=='downvote'){
            content1 = "<span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote upvote'></span>";
            content2 = " <span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote downvoted'></span>";
        }else if(action=='downvoted'){
            content1 = "<span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote upvote'></span>";
            content2 = " <span data-id='"+ myId +"' class='"+ content +" vote downvote'></span>";
        }

                $.post(url, { myId:myId, action:action }, function(data){
                    if(data=="error"){
                        alert("Error, your vote couldn't be counted.");
                    }
                    else{
                        x.html(content1+data.up+content2+data.down);
                    }

                },"json");      

        }
    });

 });
```

Please help me here. Or advice on how I can load the span `votes` only.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Its not very clear what you are trying to say here.

Comment: Where does `action` come from? And why is `upvoted` an action?

Comment: @zeroflagL check the code now. class upvote and downvote means the comment may be upvoted and downvoted. class upvoted or downvoted implies already upvoted or downvoted. Thus i get my action to do.

Comment: That's what I thought. If the action is 'upvoted' then the class will be changed to `upvote` again. So you are constantly changing between those two classes.

Comment: yes. but as the class is changed, i should be able to upvote again. @zeroflagL but am not able to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("span").click(function(){
```

An event handler is attached to all `span` elements that are **currently** on the page. You create new elements with every click. They have no handler attached. You can use

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.vote', function(...
```

That will handle the clicks on the new elements as well.

You mentioned you didn't create new elements before and it didn't work either. To solve that we would need the previous code.

Comment: Thats it. You are a lifesaver dude. Thanks a lot truely..:) And i guess the same problem was with earlier code.